# GoogleMap onCameraIdle event not firing

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to clustering the markers on google map because there's too many markers on the map (approximately 6000+ markers).

So I googled and found some documentations about marker clustering and I apply it to my source code, but markers are not shown in google map.

Partial source code of `FragMap` fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.display_map);
    if (map == null) {
        Log.e(Tag, "Google Map fragment(id: display_map) is null reference!");
        return;
    }

    map.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (DataPackage.getEQMarkerManager() == null) {
        if (!DataPackage.initializeEQMarkerManager(getActivity(), googleMap)) {
            Log.w(Tag, "EQMarkerManager initialization failure");
        }
    }
}
```

and partial source code of `EQMarkerManager` and it's implements `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener` interface.

```
public EQMarkerManager(Context ctx, GoogleMap map) {
    // ...
    clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(ctx, map);
    clusterManager.setRenderer(new EQRenderer<>(ctx, map, clusterManager));

    map.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);

    clusterManager.addItems(markers);
}

@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    Log.d(Tag, "onCameraIdle");
}
```

but `onCameraIdle` callback was never called. Why OnCameraIdle event is not firing?

gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4+'
```

Tested on Marshmallow device (SDK version 23).

**ADDED**: What is the meaning of `+` on gradle compile?

Comment: Did you receive any error message? You might miss something. Check the sample code here which demonstrate event listener: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#code_samples

Comment: @d.datul1990 thanks for your interest, but unfortunately I haven't receive any error messages :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'onCameraIdle' event was not firing because I called 'setOnCameraIdleListener' on another class.

Source code from my question

FragMap:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (DataPackage.getEQMarkerManager() == null) {
        if (!DataPackage.initializeEQMarkerManager(getActivity(), googleMap)) {
            Log.w(Tag, "EQMarkerManager initialization failure");
        }
    }
}
```

EQMarkerManager:

```
public EQMarkerManager(Context ctx, GoogleMap map) {
    // ...
    clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(ctx, map);
    clusterManager.setRenderer(new EQRenderer<>(ctx, map, clusterManager));

    map.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);

    clusterManager.addItems(markers);
}
```

initializeEQMarkerManager method does initialize EQMarkerManager class and EQMarkerManager#ctor calls setOnCameraIdleListener.
I don't know much about android, so I'm completely sure about those code works. 
But it wasn't :/

Anyway, I solve this problem by calling setOnCameraIdleListener inside of `FragMap`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (DataPackage.getEQMarkerManager() == null) {
        if (!DataPackage.initializeEQMarkerManager(getActivity())) {
            Log.w(Tag, "EQMarkerManager initialization failure");
            return;
        }
    }

    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(DataPackage.getEQMarkerManager());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'onCameraIdle' will not fire because 'setOnCameraIdleListener' is called internally by ClusterManager class . So what we can do is

```
mmap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
```

When implementing OnCameraIdleListener

```
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        clustermanager.onCameraIdle();
    }
```